# Get duration of recorded audio

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, audio-recording, microphone

I want to get the duration of the recorded audio from microphone. Currently, I'm using the method *GetSampleDuration* of the *Microphone* class.

```
totalRecordTime = microphone.GetSampleDuration(stream.ToArray().Length);
```

This works great but I think there are two problems:

1. The *stream* object contains the WAV header stuff. I don't how it affects the duration of the file? Or I can substract the WAV header length from the stream length before.
2. The method *GetSampleDuration(int sizeInBytes)*. Is it possible that the sizeInBytes parameter exceed the maximum supported Integer length?